# build failed in Cyclic during deployment

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cyclic

[Frontend package.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kyo1u.png)

[Backend package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD6Yz.png)

[server.js backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAh49.png)

T tried to deploy the website on cyclic but its saying sh: react-scripts: command not found
build failed